# Modern society with Victorian moral ideals

Tags: society

What were the highest morals of the Victorian time period?

Furthermore, what would today's society be like if we had their morals?

Comment: Hello Author, Welcome to worldbuilding! This question seems a bit broad to me. For example, hope do you define "the highest morals"?

Comment: Which society did you want us to describe? We have a lot of them in this modern age, after all. Redefining all of them is far too broad a topic for the site. And, generally, asking about changing a complete society would produce answers that are too long for the SE format to handle properly.

Answer (score 1):

Many things would be the same, but some things would be different. 
Victorian England had similar morality as our own on things like slavery and murder.  On a few things there would be very different.

1.Sex, the people of victory England weren't exactly puritans by any stretch of imagination, sex outside of marriage wasn't completely unusually, but during the victory was still uncommon and at the very least frowned upon by the majority, especially for woman.

2. Homosexuality would be considered very unacceptable by most of society. For part of victory reign Homosexuality was punishable by death.